# image zoom option in dialogbox android

Tags: android, image, zooming, dialog

I need to apply zoom in and zoom out functionality to my image view that display in dialog box.

I could able to put the image in dialog box , now i need to add zoom in and zoom out options to it..

i have done the code like this,

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.lesson_full_image);
         dialog.setTitle(filetitle);  
         ImageView bmImage = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lessonimg);
         bmImage.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(fileurl));
         dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

*Create a layout file as **layout_full_image.xml.*** Add following imageview and button in this layout

```
 <com.zoomimage.helper.TouchImageView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/img_receipt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_dissmiss"
    style="@style/MyButton"
    android:text="Dismiss"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/normal_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_purple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

Use this link download https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView **TouchImageView.java** file, Add this file in your project.

Now write code on a imageview's OnClickListener for which you have to show show zoom effect.

```
 holder.img_rcpt_selected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(orderDetailFragment.getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_full_image);
            TouchImageView bmImage = (TouchImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_receipt);
            bmImage.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(orderDetailFragment.getfile.getPath()));
            Button button=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dissmiss);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go is to use a webview. Since you are using a filepath, putting an image in a webview and making it scrollable is very simple. If you would like to keep it in the same activity then you could still use a dialog with a webview in it. For example:

```
public void showZoomableImage(String fileUrl) {
     Dialog d = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    d.setCancelable(true);
    WebView wv = new WebView(mContext);
    wv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    wv.loadUrl(fileUrl);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true)
    d.setContentView(iv);
    d.show();
}
```